# How to verify a column value in selenium java and based on that value present or not need to verify the another column value

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Suppose I have the below table:

[image]

use case: If the Part1 is present in the Col2 of the first row then verify the value of the col3 in the first row is Release. Similarly, if the Part2 is present in the Col2 of the second row then verify the value of the col3 in the second row is Release.

How can I achieve this using selenium java?

Please find the code below which I tried:

public boolean verifyPartsinEBOM(String partName, String partState) {

```
    boolean result = true;
    //To locate the table in the EBOM page.
    WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.id("tbr"));
    
    //To locate rows of table. 
    List < WebElement > rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    
    //To calculate no of rows In table.
    int rows_count = rows_table.size();
    
    //Loop will execute till the last row of table.
    for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
        
        //To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
        List < WebElement > columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        
        //To calculate no of columns (cells). In that specific row.
        int columns_count = columns_row.size();
        System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
        
        //Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
        for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
            
            // To retrieve text from that specific cell.
            String celtext = columns_row.get(column).getText();
            if(celtext.contains(partName)) {
                WebElement state = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbr']/tbody/tr["+Integer.toString(row+1)+"]/td["+Integer.toString(column+3)+"]"));
                String pState = state.getText();
                if(pState.contains(partState)) {
                result = true;
                break;
                }
                else {
                    result = false;
                }
                
                break;
            }
            
            else {
                result = false;
            }               
        }          
    }       
    
    return result;      
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the code what you have tried so far? Also share the HTML of the table.

Comment: @Shwan I am unable to break from the for loop that I used for "rows". I want to break from the for loop I am using for rows once the data is found.